# Remove a ending character from each line on Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

So it reads from a online source file
the string look like this,

```
1. this is line1.X
2. this is "line2X"
3. this is X line4.
4. this is line3.X.X
```

So I only wants to put out the whole string with the ending "X" removed. In this example, only the X at the end of line 1 and line 4 will be removed.
I used chomp, but it only removed the X in line4.

```
string.each_line { |line| line.chomp("X") }
```

Should I use chomp or use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String#chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) will work if you change the record separator to include both your chosen character *and* a newline. For example:

```
string.each_line { |line| puts line.chomp("X\n") }
```

The code above will print:

```
1. this is line1.
2. this is "line2X"
3. this is X line4.
4. this is line3.X.
```

but it will still return the original string. This may or may not matter for your use case. If it does matter, then you may want to use [Kernel#p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) and [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) instead. For example:

```
p string.gsub(/X$/, '')
#=> "1. this is line1.\n2. this is \"line2X\"\n3. this is X line4.\n4. this is line3.X.\n"

string
#=> "1. this is line1.X\n2. this is \"line2X\"\n3. this is X line4.\n4. this is line3.X.X\n"
```

Comment: Cary Swoveland's answer is a better way to do it because it wouldn't remove the newline from the string and just removes the trailing "X".

Comment: @DarshanRai You're clearly not understanding what happens when you chomp/puts with #each_line, and are concerning yourself with a non-issue. Run the code and see. On the other hand, if you're concerned about benchmarks, feel free to run some timing code and report back about which is faster, but either approach will be fast enough for the OP's corpus.

Comment: gsub works and thanks for the explanation.  the chomp("X\n") works only if the last line doesn;t contain a X

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string.each_line { |line|
  if line[-1] = 'X'
    line.chop!
  end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `gsub`?

```
text =<<_
1. this is line1.X
2. this is "line2X"
3. this is X line4.
4. this is line3.X.X
_

puts text.gsub(/X$/,'')
  # 1. this is line1.
  # 2. this is "line2X"
  # 3. this is X line4.
  # 4. this is line3.X.
```

Comment: @Gagan, it's just one way of denoting the end of a heredoc. It does the same job as `text <<=THE_BITTER_END...<lines of text>...THE_BITTER_END`. I noticed @sawa using it many moons ago, and thought it was nice and clean.